# Falsi method algorithm

Tags: matlab

I wrote a falsi method code and I got problem with **fa** function. My general function is in interval [a,b]=[2,12], as I defined in main script:

```
 a=2;
 b=12;
 %Function
 syms x real;
 f=1.2*sin(x)+2*log(x+2)-5;
```

I wonder how to correctly pass argument **a** to the function **fa** and, in general, to **falsi method function** . I guess, it cannot be just '2', it must be dynamic somehow. Thanks for tips ! :)

```
 function [ x ] = task1_falsi( f, x, a)
 % Defining functions
 a=2;
 fa=feval(f,a);
 f=inline(f);
 fa=inline(fa);
 err=1;

% Falsi's loop.
% Stops when error is negligible or number of iterations becomes  prohibitive
it=0;
while (it<1000) && (err>10e-5)
% Falsi's algorithm
x1=x-feval(f,x)*(x-a)/fa;

% Calculating error
err=abs(x1-x);

% New zero is previous value
x=x1;
it=it+1;

%Showing steps
fprintf('%d\t%f \n',it, x); 
end

disp('Root:');
disp(x);
disp('Iterations:');
disp(it);
end
```

Comment: For every value of `a` you want to run this function right? As this is a recursive algorithm, I think you have to use a loop somewhere. Either use a `for` loop within the function itself, or call the function from within a `for` loop.

Comment: I would like to do so, but I dont know the requirement from the teacher. I got a=2 set in the excersise. Maybe I shouldn't do it dynamically... But if it will be static, as in the exmple above, how to implement it crreclt to make fa function run properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  %Task 1
     % Falsi's method algorithm

 function [ x ] = task1_falsi( f, x)
  err=1;
  y = 7;                  % Starting point
 z = 8; 
 f=inline(f);
  % Ending point
  maxIteration = 1000;     % Maximum number of iterations
epsilon = 0.001;        % Accuracy
it=0;      % Vector with number of iterations
xold = z;               % Variable used for calculations
   solutionRegulaFalsix=zeros(10,1);   % Error vector
for  j=0:20
 while (it <= maxIteration)
     x1 = y - ((feval(f,y)*(z-y))/(feval(f,z)-feval(f,y))); % Calculating the root
    it= it+ 1;
    if (abs(x1-xold)<epsilon*abs(x1)) % Accuracy condition
        break;
    else
        xold = x1;
        if feval(f,y)*feval(f,z) > 0
            y = x1;       % Starting point is being changed
        else
            z = x1;       % Ending point is being changed
        end
    end
end
    err = abs(x1-x);     % Calculating the error

   % epsilon = epsilon/10;
   %Showing steps
fprintf('%d\t%f \n',it, x); 
y=2; 
   z=3;

   disp('Root:');
   disp(x1);
  disp('Iterations:');
   disp(it);
  end
    end
```